# How to insert many mutations in a single GraphQL request?

Tags: graphql

I using https://hygraph.com/, and I want insert (create many products) in a single GraphQL request.

At the moment I know how to insert one product:

```
mutation {
  createProduct(data: { title: "Face Mask", slug: "dfavce-mask", price: 1000 }) {
    id
  }
}
```

I read the documentation, but I didn't see information about bulk creation records.

Link for hygraph documentation:

https://hygraph.com/docs/api-reference/content-api/mutations#create-entries

Answer (score 0):

The top-level query you show is just a query against the `Mutation` type (or another type specified in the schema).  Like any other query, it can have multiple fields.  At a technical level, the only special thing about GraphQL mutations is that, if you do have multiple fields, [they execute sequentially](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#multiple-fields-in-mutations).

Also like other queries, if you want to request the same field multiple times (run similarly-named mutations) you need to use an [alias](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments) to disambiguate the results.

```
mutation {
  createFaceMask: createProduct(data: { title: "Face Mask" }) { id }
  createHandSanitizer: createProduct(data: { title: "Hand Sanitizer" }) { id }
}
```